# Verify solution to PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Define $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ by  $u(x,y)= e^{x\sin y}f(x-y)$, where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function. Show that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=(\sin y+x\cos y)u.$$

**My attempt**

We have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\sin y\cdot e^{x\sin y}f(x-y)+e^{x\sin y}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x-y)$$ and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=x\cos y\cdot e^{x\sin y}f(x-y)+e^{x\sin y}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}f(x-y).$$

So, in order to show the given equality, I have to show that $$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}f(x-y)=-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x-y).\tag{$*$}$$ Now, I am not really sure how to do this but it seems rather obvious. I even tested a few random differentiable functions and saw that it is true, as expected.

So, any hints as to how can I prove $(*)$ are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps just think about $f(x-y)$ in terms of composition $f(g(x,y)),$ where $g(x,y)=x-y.$ Now by chain rule we should get $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(g(x,y))=\frac{df(u)}{du}\cdot \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y},$ which is just $-\frac{df(u)}{du}.$ The expression for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(g(x,y))$ can be derived analogically.